# Flexslider loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flexslider

I'm using the jQuery plugin easytabs to load HTML from another page. The HTML may consist of a jQuery flexslider, but the slider doesn't work after it has been loaded since the JavaScript already has been run. Here's my code:

```
<ul class="portfolio-thumbnails">
    <li><a href="portfolio.html #item1" data-target="#item1">Load via ajax</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel-container">
    <div id="item1" class="portfolio-item"></div> /* The slider loaded from the ajax call will be appended to this div */
</div>
```

I have tried calling the flexslider when I click on the Load via ajax link, like so:

```
$(".portfolio-thumbnails li a").click(function () { 
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
});
```

...but that only works the second time when I click. I guess the flexslider script is being called before it has loaded the HTML via ajax. I have also tried calling the flexslider script from the external page (portfolio.html), but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put it in your `success` callback of your easy tab ajax request?
Append the following to your easytab event:

```
  .bind('easytabs:ajax:complete', function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
  });
```

Found under [event-hooks](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#event-hooks) in the documentation:

RESPONSE TO NOT LOADING AFTER TAB CLICK

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I don't have ajax request like that. I use the easytabs jQuery plugin, which looks like this:

`$('#portfolio-tabs').easytabs({
    transitionIn: 'slideDown',
    transitionOut: 'slideUp',
    collapsible: true,
    updateHash: false
});`

So I don't have anywhere to put my success/done code.

Comment: I updated my answer to adjust to easy tab. If you still can't get it we may need to see your easytab event call.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that worked! Here's my working code:

    $('#portfolio-tabs').easytabs();
    $('#portfolio-tabs').bind('easytabs:ajax:complete', function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide"
        });
    });

Comment: Unmarked this as an accepted answer. This only works if the slideshow is the first clicked portfolio item. See here: http://graphic-dev.com/templates/virtual-businesscard/#portfolio

If you click on slideshow first, then it works, but if you click on any other item and then the slideshow item, then it doesn't load the images...

Comment: The answer is not wrong, your js is wrong. You are making the width of the container that's holding the images to be 0px wide. if you remove the attribute the container is back or if you click on one of the slider handlers it comes back. You have a attached event somewhere that is making the width 0.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea where that event would be triggered... I have not written any code which changes the widhts. It might be a bug with the slider plugin...

Comment: I imagine it might be this line here :// Carousel Options itemWidth: 0, in your jquery.custom.js

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that... All that does is change the width of each slide, so more than one image can be shown at the same time. The width is still set to 0 at first. Btw, I tried with another slider plugin and it was the same problem then so it's probably not the slider.

Comment: I finally got it to work by changing the slider animation setting from "slide" to "fade"! I would really like to use slide since that makes more sense when you swipe it on a smart phone/tablet, but at least it works...

Comment: use both... paste the code you have for the fade, Im sure we can alter it to just show() and still use slide.

Comment: `$('#portfolio-tabs').bind('easytabs:ajax:complete', function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade"
        });
    });`

See full list of slider settings here: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: Can you try $('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "fade" }).show();

Comment: That didn't change anything. Not sure why that would make the images slide instead of fade?

Comment: sorry i meant `$('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: "slide" }).show();`

Comment: I tried that as well, but I still have the width of 0 problem.